# Object not in the right state; which exception is appropriate?

Tags: python, exception

Say I have a

```
class Rocket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ready = False

    def prepare_for_takeoff(self):
        self.ready = True

    def takeoff(self):
        if not self.ready:
            raise NotReadyException("not ready!")
        print("Liftoff!")
```

Now, which of the [standard exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html) would be most appropriate to derive `NotReadyException` from? Would it be `ValueError`, since `self` has the wrong state/value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now, which of the standard exceptions would be most appropriate to derive NotReadyException from?

`Exception`

Don't mess with anything else.

http://code.google.com/p/soc/wiki/PythonStyleGuide#Exceptions

What are your use cases for exception handling?

If you derived your exception from, say `ValueError`, would you ever write a handler that used `except ValueError:` to catch both exceptions and handle them in exactly the same way?  Unlikely.

`ValueError` is a catch-all when more specific exceptions aren't appropriate.  Your exception is very specific.

When you have an application-specific exception like this, the odds of it sharing any useful semantics with a built-in exception are low.  The odds of actually combining the new one and an existing exception into a single handler are very, very low.

About the only time you'll ever combine an application-specific exception with generic exceptions is to use `except Exception:` in some catch-all logger.

Comment: My use case is mainly that I prefer to document my interface as throwing some kind of built-in exception, but have the freedom to actually throw a subtype so I can do more fine-grained handling "privately" when the need arises. Does your advice still apply? I don't like to clutter the interface with library-specific exception classes.

Comment: @larsmans: The standard advice is one application-specific exception in the module for external API purposes.  Often with a generic name like "Error", so clients can do `except module.Error:`.

Comment: @larsmans: The use case for documentation isn't the point.  The use case for handling is the indicator.  If you aren't going to handle your exception and `ValueError` **exactly** the same way, then they're not the same thing.  Class definitions encapsulate structure and behavior.  Exception structure is usually uninteresting.  Exception behavior is the interesting use case.  And that boils down to the `except` clauses more than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just derive it from `Exception`. Programmers who catch `ValueError` might be quite surprised that they catch your `NotReadyException` as well.

If you will be defining a lot of similar types of state-related exceptions, and it would be convenient to be able to catch 'em all, you might define a `StateError` exception and then derive `NotReadyException` from that.

Comment: ... unless I were to document it as throwing `ValueError`, right?

Comment: I write documentation for a living, and even I'm aware that hardly anyone ever reads it.  :-)  "Principle of least astonishment" doesn't include reading docs.